# MySQL strange group by resultset

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run following MySQL query

```
SELECT city, count(email) 
FROM ratings
WHERE ratedDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30';
GROUP BY city;
```

This query returns a single result set e.g:

> Istanbul | 54574

I am expecting multiple result from above query. As rated from multiple city. I tried following query to see how many cities have rated in the date range

```
SELECT distinct city
FROM ratings
WHERE ratedDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30';
```

The result of this query is however different and reruns multiple records.

> Tokyo
>
> Kive
>
> Lahore
>
> ....and so on

**I just need to get the count of email city wide.**

Please do not **mark duplicate** for those who are writing sub queries

Answer (score 3):

There is a `;` in the middle of your statement that ignores the `group by`